# How to make Qwt accepts touch and multi-touch events?

Tags: c++, qt, touch, qwt

I subclass the QwtPlot,like this:

```
class MyQwtPlot:public QwtPlot
{    
 public:    
 private:    
 protected:    
       bool event(QEvent *event);    
}
```

But the event doesn't accept touch and multi-touch event.Could anyone tell me how to make it accept touch event?Thank you very much!

Answer (score 0):

The man behind Qwt wrote [this statement](http://www.qtcentre.org/archive/index.php/t-46868.html).

When your drivers support multi touch, I think the [QTouchEvent](http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-4.8/qtouchevent.html) class will help you. 
Note especially the following:

> To receive touch events, widgets have to have the Qt::WA_AcceptTouchEvents attribute set

Comment: Hello Corijn
    Thank you!Now the event can accept the touch event,and works well.But when I add the QwtPlotCurve->attach(this);in MyQwtPlot,the event doesn't accept touch event,but it accepts other events;Do you know why?Thank you!

Comment: I don't really understand what you mean. After adding the curve, the event(QEvent *event) does not capture `QTouchEvent`s anymore?

Comment: can you post a minimal version of your code, which illustrates the problem?